# How to customize my shiny sidebarpanel to make it more beautiful with css

Tags: css, r, shiny

```
ui <- dashboardPage(skin="black",
                    
                    dashboardHeader(
                      title = HTML(
                        "<div style='font-size: 20px; 
                        font-family: Pacifico, cursive; 
                        font-weight: bold; 
                        font-style: italic; 
                        color: red; 
                        margin-left: 0px;'>TRAJECTOIRE-PATIENTS</div>"
                      ),
                      titleWidth = 300
                    ),
  dashboardSidebar(width = 250,
 
                   div(style="font-size:10px;",
                                   sidebarMenu(
                                     menuItem( "Analyse de la concurrence",
                                               menuSubItem("Cartographie sur les hopitaux", tabName = "StatHopital"),
                                               menuSubItem("Cartographie sur les communes",tabName = "StatCommune"),

                                                           div(style="font-size:12px;",


                                                               
                                                               selectInput("LibGHM", 
                                                                           label = div(style = "display: flex; align-items: center;",
                                                                                       HTML(paste0('<i class="fas fa-user-md" style="color: white; margin-right: 5px;" title="Doctor"></i>')),
                                                                                       "Spécialités"),
                                                                           choices = c("Total",levels(as.factor(LETTERS))),
                                                                           selected="Total"
                                                               ),
                                                              

                                                               uiOutput("ui"),

                                                              
                                                               
                                                               selectInput("Urgence", 
                                                                           label = div(style = "display: flex; align-items: center;",
                                                                                       HTML(paste0('<i class="fas fa-ambulance" style="color: white; margin-right: 5px;" title="Ambulance"></i>')),
                                                                                       "Urgence"),
                                                                           choices = c("Total",levels(as.factor(LETTERS))),
                                                                           selected="Total"
                                                               ),

                                                              
                                                               selectInput("Majorite", 
                                                                           label = div(style = "display: flex; align-items: center;",
                                                                                       HTML(paste0('<i class="fas fa-user" style="color: white; margin-right: 10px;" title="Doctor"></i>')),
                                                                                       HTML(paste0('<i class="fas fa-child" style="color: white; margin-right: 5px;" title="Child"></i>')),
                                                                                       "Majorité"),
                                                                           choices = c("Total",levels(as.factor(LETTERS[1:3]))),
                                                                           selected="Total"
                                                               ),

                                                               selectInput(inputId = "Zone",
                                                                           label=div(style = "display: flex; align-items: center;",
                                                                                  HTML(paste0('<i class="fas fa-bullseye" style="color: white; margin-right: 5px;" title="Child"></i>')),
                                                                                  "Seuil de Zone de récrutement"),
                                                                           choices = c("Ensemble des patients","Zone de recrutement","Zone d'attraction"),
                                                                           selected="Zone de recrutement"),
                                                               

                                                               selectInput(inputId ="indicateur",div(style = "display: flex; align-items: center;",
                                                                           HTML(paste0('<i class="fas fa-chart-line" style="color: white; margin-right: 5px;" title=""></i>')),
                                                                           "Indicateurs"),
                                                                           choices = c("Nombre de patients"="nb_patient_tot",
                                                                                       "Nombre de patients rapporté à la population"="nb_patient_pop")))



                                                           )







                                   )
  )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$style(type = "text/css",
               "html, body {width:100%;height:100%}",

               ".leaflet .legend {
                                         font-size: 8px;
                                       line-height: 6px;}",

               ".leaflet .legend i{
                                       width: 8px;
                                       height: 8px;
                                       }"
    ),
    tags$head(
      tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css")
    )



    )
)


server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I am using these codes to try to customize my sidebarpanel.

Inside the dashboardpage:

```
tags$head(
      tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css")
    )
```

And inside the the css file

```
.dashboard-sidebar .sidebar {
  background-color: #FF0000; /* Change to your desired color */
}
```

to make a basic changes, such as the background color:

The css file is inside the `www directory`

Bit I can't change anything in the sidebarpanel.

I'd be happy to have someone help me make the application more attractive.